# Unir dados para Mala direta | Tabela pai e filho

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Eu tenho uma planilha com dados de alunos. Para cada disciplina de um mesmo aluno há uma linha específica. Eu gostaria de fazer uma mala direta com apenas um e-mail por aluno, mas que importasse os dados de todas as matérias.

Tabela:
Primeira coluna tem o ID do aluno, cada aluno tem o seu. Segunda e terceira nome e sobrenome respectivamente. Quarta e Quinta Coluna ID e nome da Matéria, e por fim na sexta e da sétima em diante o desempenho do aluno em cada matéria.

Exemplo:

> ID.......Nome e Sobr......ID e nome matéria......Acesso......Nota 1..n2..n3..n4
>   1234 .....João Silva.............3
>   Português............28/04...........1.........2....5....4

Como faço para que em uma página venham todas as disciplinas de um aluno? Exemplo acima, mais Matemática, Ciências, Raciocínio, etc

Answer (score 1):

Você tem em sua tabela:

```
ID      Nome e Sobr ID e nome matéria   Acesso  Nota 1  n2  n3  n4
1234    João Silva      3 Português     28/04   1       2   5   4
1234    João Silva      4 Matemática    28/04   1       2   5   4
1234    João Silva      5 História      28/04   1       2   5   4

7890    Maria Oliveira  3 Português     26/04   1       2   5   4
7890    Maria Oliveira  4 Matemática    26/04   1       2   5   4
7890    Maria Oliveira  5 História      26/04   1       2   5   4
```

Você tem uma única tabela que tem todas estas informações e quer que as agrupem por aluno, matéria contendo as informações que fiquem  neste formato correto?

Então comece organizando os dados, caso a ordem não esteja de acordo com o que você queira enviar no e-mail.

A propósito onde está o endereço de e-mail?

Suponho que está no mesmo arquivo, como segue.

```
ID      Nome e Sobr     ID e nome matéria   Acesso  Nota 1  n2  n3  n4  email
1234    João Silva      3 Português         28/04   2       5   4   4   joao@silva.com.br
1234    João Silva      4 Matemática        28/04   1       2   5   4   joao@silva.com.br
1234    João Silva      5 História          28/04   1       2   5   4   joao@silva.com.br

7890    Maria Oliveira  3 Português         26/04   1       2   5   4   maria@olivira.com.br
7890    Maria Oliveira  4 Matemática        26/04   1       2   5   4   maria@olivira.com.br
7890    Maria Oliveira  5 História          26/04   1       2   5   4   maria@olivira.com.br
```

Organizada a planilha, não sei como irá criar o email, mas possivelmente uma macro onde através de um laço (`while`, `repeat`), leia o email e enquanto o email não for diferente monta o email com as informações, quando o email for diferente envia o email e reinicia o processo para o próximo, assim até o final do arquivo.

A propósito, como está utilizando planilha, no momento que enviar o e-mail, salve na última coluna a informação que enviou o email, assim você não o enviará novamente.